# How to secure appspec file?

Tags: aws-codedeploy

What's the best way to ensure that developers can't modify the contents of the appspec.yml file used by AWS CodeDeploy? This file executes scripts on production servers with root privileges so it would be ideal if there were a way to ensure the files can't be modified by anyone with access to the application repository.

Please note that I'm looking for technical suggestions.

Please also note I'm using CodeDeploy as part of CodePipeline with GitHub as source.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The way I handled this in the past was to have a separate repository that contains the scripts, as most of them ended up shared across multiple projects anyway.  Then your `appspec.yml` file just contains references to the scripts and imports them via a submodule.  It's not perfect because a developer could change the `appspec.yml` to call his own scripts instead, although that's a lot more obvious.

Another approach I have used on Azure is to require that scripts are signed with a specific GPG key.  I used a PowerShell and a CodeSigning certificate, but I suspect there is an equally suitable solution with GPG.

A final approach would be to automatically fail the build or [reject the commit](https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2015/05/31/use-git-pre-commit-hooks-to-stop-unwanted-commits/) if changes are detected within `appspec.yml` except when those changes are made by an "approved" person.

Answer (score 1):

You could store this file in a Version Control System (VCS) like [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) and ensure that the developers can only merge it when a pull request has been approved by you.

Comment: Do you mean merge with the main application repo? The problem is this is part of a CodePipeline that executes on push to the application repository. Are you suggesting having a post commit hook that pulls in the appspec.yml file from a different repo? I'd have to check but this might break the execution of the pipeline